# sapui5 badge on button to appear as in cozy mode

Tags: sapui5

im trying to get a badge on a button to appear on the top right corner (like survey button in the sdk https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/ )

but unless im changing the entire app density mode to cozy nothing works,

but debugging the the https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/ site, i see the entire app in in compact mode, and the survey button appear as in cozy mode..

if im looking at the give feedback button
[button with badge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BmlI.png)

it got a class of surveyButton, once removing it, the button returns to inline badge instead of top right badge

figured it got to do something with css related.

found this:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/documentation/sdk/css/style.css

the class surveyButton is here, but adding this properties changes nothing to the inline badge button

anybody got any idea how sap did that ?